# New emulators and shared user android.uid.system for test butler

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was happily using test butler before. But now with new emulators (26,27) I am getting this error:

```
Failed to install test-butler-app-1.3.1.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.linkedin.android.testbutler-Fyya9bfxBI9dEauibDCf8g==: Package com.linkedin.android.testbutler has no signatures that match those in shared user android.uid.system; ignoring!]
```

And even when I create a new emulator with API 25 which was working before I am now getting this error. Anyone knows where to get emulator-images where I can still use shared user android.uid.system and with it test butler?

I do not need google-api's for the devices running these ui-tests - but it seems you cannot get emulators without them anymore.

Comment: The android emulator should just use the default keys from the android aosp source code.  test butler creates their signature keystore from those same keys. Are you building the test butler apk or is it from somewhere else?  If your building it, have you changed anything in your gradle configs that would alter test butlers signing config?

Comment: I can reproduce this with the official linedin test-butler apks. Also these very same apk's worked before ..